# How to add new values to nested Core Data objects?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

My Core Data object model has three nested objects as shown below:

```
Item
  Beverage
    Brand
```

When I first create an instance of Item

```
Item *item = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:self.objectContext];
```

the item.beverage property is nil. Next I want to store a value in the item.beverage.brand.title property.

Do I have to create an instance of Beverage and assign it to item.beverage, then create an instance of Brand and assign it to item.beverage.brand.

```
item.beverage = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Beverage" inManagedObjectContext:self.objectContext];

item.beverage.brand = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Brand" inManagedObjectContext:self.objectContext];
```

before I can finally assign the value to the title property?

```
item.beverage.brand.title=@"Sample Title";
```

Is there a shorter/less verbose way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create each object in the object graph.  I'm not aware of any core-data provided shortcuts.  You could of course write your own methods, categories, or macros to reduce the verbosity if you find your self writing a lot of boiler plate code.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of your separate entities is primarily encapsulation of behavior or normalization of data, it sometimes occurs that you never wish to insert a parent without automatically inserting a child. In your case, this could be an Item that always, without fail, has a Beverage.

In this case, you could set the relationship between Item and Beverage to be non-optional and to-one, with a cascading delete rule. Together, these reflect the fact that the one is meaningless without the other. Unfortunately, in that case, insertion of the Item *still does not* insert the Beverage. To do that, override `awakeFromInsert` to perform this insertion and then it will be automatically present whenever an instance of Item is created.

If on the other hand it is possible that an Item may not have a Beverage, but that when it does, that Beverage always has a name, as the other poster commented, it's also a possibility that adding custom logic - `Item.setBrandname`, which inserts a Beverage if it is not already present - is a viable solution.

Your business logic drives this kind of decision.

Also, fwiw, 'item', while not a reserved keyword, may be a good word to avoid as a class/variable name because it's an abstract/programming-related concept. That's entirely separate from the rest of my answer. ;-)